# Cplex coding. (Directed graph)

Tags: cplex, directed-acyclic-graphs

Good day. sir

I have some trouble with Cplex for coding a directed graph.

the example picture as following..
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6ljU.png)

So, now I'm trying to make a set of arc such as
Set_of_arc = [(1,2),(1,3),(2,5),(4,5)]

that means node1 and 2 are connected by arc (1,2) and node 1 and 3 are connected by arc(1,3)...and so on..

and then I will make constraints like (node2 - node1 = weight12)

by using Cplex.. I can not represent what I wanna do.

If you give me the answer, then it will be very helpful to me. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tuple edge
{
  key int o;
  key int d;
  float weight;
}

{edge} edges =
{
  <1,2,12>,
  <1,3,23>,
  <2,5,34>,
  <3,4,45>,
  <4,5,56>
};

float w45=item(edges,<4,5>).weight;

execute
{
  writeln("w45=",w45);
}
```

gives

```
56
```